# Free Shipping orders over 100$ AND Free shipping with Coupon Code

Tags: magento2, shipping, coupon

Im currently kinda struggeling. I did set free shipping for orders over 100$ in Stores->Configuration->Shipping Methods.
[image]

Now I created a Coupon Code which gives 5$ discount on a product (that works so far) and should also give free shipping for that product. I set "Free shipping: For matching Items only", but it doesnt work.

Does it maybe not work because I have set a minimum order amount of 100$ to get free shipping in the Stores->Configuration->Shipping Methods options?

Any idea how to fix?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First You need to disable free shipping and enable flatrate.
- After that you need to set two different rules from the shopping cart
  price rules.
- One Will be for free shipping over order of 100$ and another one for
  5$ discount along with  free shipping discount (//your conditions
  here).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot for the comment. The Free Shipping rule worked now, but the rule for the 5$ Discout AND Free Shipping didnt work.. It only gives 5$ Discout but no free shipping ..  Also if my order is over 100$ AND I use the coupon 5$ + free shipping, then I need to pay shipping fees even if the subtotal is over 100$..

Comment: what conditions are you using for both the rules?

Comment: I need to do something different. I need to activate free shipping if order amount is only more than 150$. that 150$ should be the final amount after all discounts and deductions. In my case, lets say if there's product is 150$ and discount is 5$, then final amount is 145$. So free shipping must be disabled. but it's still enabled for me. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Joey I'm having the same issue. Have you by any chance found a solution?